# Session, location command is not working in 000webhost

Tags: php, mysql

This is my index page

```
  <?php     
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['name']='Guru';     
        echo $_SESSION['name'];
        header("Location:logout.php");
    ?>
```

This is my logout page

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

Session_destroy();

echo"<center>YOU ARE LOGGED OUT<center>";
?>
<br>click here<a href="login.php">TO LOGIN</a>
</body>
</html>
```

this not redirect me to logout page but it is worked well in xampp server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add full url in header function.Also there is some typo.

```
header("location:http://example.com/logout.php");
 try following 
Also there is some typo try following code
session_destroy(); OR unset($_SESSION['name']);
```